# toString() Method, String.format() method. how can I adjust String Lines

Tags: java, string, swing, format

plz, Look at my codes. I have wanted to print some of the data Objects in JList. so, I used the String.format() method to print Objects neatly. but the unexpected result has arisen.

```
public String toString() {

    return String.format("%s%15s%12s%10s%6d학점%15s%8s%6d%10s-%s", this.classification, this.name, this.department, this.professor,this.credit, this.schedule, this.classRoom, this.nop, this.number, this.division);
}
```

[Wrong Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x19jw.png)

I think it caused by the difference in volume between the Korean Alphabet and space characters.

So, I tried to use '\t' escape sequences but it didn't work.

How can I print it like this picture?
[advisable result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pkwzh.png)

and I appreciate advice about my Question form.

Comment: what do you mean by 'the unexpected result'?

Comment: _I think it caused by the difference in volume between the Korean Alphabet and space characters_ I think you are right. If there is a fixed-width Korean font, then try using it. Simply call method `setFont()` on your `JList` instance.

Comment: Maybe a JTable might give you a better display?